# Custom Managed Object Intermittently Hangs in Relationship Accessor

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, relationship

On iOS (using Xcode 4, iPad Simulator 4.3) I have an "Article" entity and an "Author" entity. There are two relationships connecting these two (an article has an "authors" relationship [optional, to-many] and an author also has an "articles" [optional, to-many]).

If I start from an empty database (starting from scratch, removing the app from the simulator and hitting debug again). It works fine, I can add like hundreds of items to the database without a problem.

BUT if I add some items to the database first and then stop the app (press home button or not) and start again (hit the debug button again) the data is there, I can "read" the data fine and I can add data to other entities fine. But when I add new authors (and not articles), *sometimes* the press stops on the second line of this function in my "Author.m" class (which is a subclass of NSManagedObject):

```
- (void)addArticlesObject:(Article *)value {    
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];  
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"articles" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];  
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"articles"] addObject:value];  
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"articles" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];  
    [changedObjects release];  
}
```

WITHOUT any messages in the console (debuger output) and if I step forward I would be sent to `__CFTypeCollectionRetain` and then get a EXC_BADACCESS .

This final step is not always the same, some times it just wont return and CPU goes to 100% (50% actually it's a dual core machine) until I hit stop or kill the "app's" process (xcode responds fine).

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Does anyone know what    `__CFTypeCollectionRetain`    does? related to core data.

Comment: It's an internal Core Foundation class.

Comment: Thanks @TechZen, How come I don't get any exceptions or any other debugger messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was a result of custom managed object classes not being in sync with the data model. Apparently I changed a relation's to-many or optional property and did not regenerate the custom classes. Now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking at an infinite loop caused by side effects of the two sided to-many relationship e.g. when you add an `Article` object to a `Author` object that causes the `Article` object to add another `Author` instance which in turn adds another `Article` and so on...

This would not produce any immediate errors because very long loops are often part of the code. The error you are getting suggest that you encounter some kind of overflow situation in a Core Foundation object that retains collection (arrays, dictionaries, sets) objects.

Check all your custom accessors for side effects to make sure you are not triggering a loop. You can put log statements inside the accessors to see when they are being called. That will let you see the loop.

Comment: Maybe! I don't have any custom written accessors. But I should look more carefully. Putting NSLog s in the accessors is a good test to see if there is an infinite loop. I have made more changed to the schema and regenerated all the managed object classes, but this problem is still there. I'll update you if I figured it out.

Comment: Zen, Nope! I put NSLog in all the "add" and "remove" functions and they are called as I expect them to be called. No infinite loops.

Comment: I can't advise further with what info you have provided. I can tell you that the behavior you describe: the absence of errors and  especially the near total consumption of CPU indicates an infinite loop somewhere.